# From this / By this / With this

Tags: expressions

> He argued that we are so helpless at birth that  if the first human
>   had been put into the world on their own, they would immediately have
>   died. **From this**, he concluded that human beings arose from other
>   animals with more self reliant newborns.

Here, can **From this** be replaced with **By this** or **With this**?

I wonder if three of them are somehow different each other and if all three are common expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I think all three would be understood, "from this" seems the most correct.

To restate what's happening in your quote: he's making an argument ("he argued"), and then drawing a conclusion **from** it ("he concluded").

(You could also say "**by** making the argument, he reached a conclusion", or "he reached the conclusion **with** the argument he made", so I think they're all justifiable, but I'd say the first way is most obvious.)